# Form Upload Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

Here is my question i have a combobox

```
<select id='addOPTION' onchange='fillADDid(this.value);'>
<option value=0>Select</option>
<option value=1>etc</option>
<option value=2>etc</option>
<option value=3>invoice</option>
</select>
```

that when i select invoice in my function

```
...

     if(str=='3'){
        $.get("/php/home/add/produto/fillInvoice.php", function(html) {
                    $("#addFIELD").html(html);

            });

...
```

it generates a form within a table to fill an invoice data:

```
...

<form id="adicionar" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" id="newname"></td>
<td><input type="date" id="newdate"></td>
<input type="file" id="myfile" name="newdir" accept="application/pdf"></td>
<td class="btn"><input class="add" onclick="return validar();" type="submit" id="submit_btn" value=""></td>
</tr></tbody></table></div>
```

So when i submit the form it calls this ajax function to submit it dynamically:

```
...

var dataString = 'newname='+ name +'&newdate='+ date +'&newvendor_id='+ vendor +'&newdir='+ dir;

    $.ajax({  
      type: "POST",  
      url: "/php/home/add/invoice/addinvoice.php",  
      data: dataString,  
      success: function(data) {  
      //alert(data);
            if(data==0){
                    alert('REPEATED');      

                }else{
                    if(data==1){ var pdf="with PDF"; }else{ var pdf="without PDF";}

                    var result = confirm("Invoice inserted "+pdf+"!\n\nClear form?");
                    if(result){
                            document.getElementById('adicionar').reset();
                }
               }

               }

    }); 
...
```

So after it calls the php that submits the data to the mysql database...

After this explanation of my code i was wondering why doesnt my upload work? is it because its dynamic?, so the upload time differs from the submit? ...it works on normal inputs... how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
data:{'newname':name,'newdate':date,'newvendor_id':vendor,'newdir':dir}
```

replace datastring with this

Comment: The php receives that?

Comment: you can recive them in the $_POST[] as usual.u can access them as $_POST['newname'] etc.

Comment: here i think u are trying to post file through ajax. files cannot be posted like form submit in jquery.you need some other libraries for that